# Regex Javascript formatting decimals numbers with comma and not with dot

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I have this formatting for decimals numbers

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Anyone can help me to create the same effect but with comma and not with dot for divide decimal part?
Thank you

Comment: And did you try replacing `.` with `,`?

Answer (score 2):

Just change `\.` to `,`.

```
/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

*I don't even know how is this an answer*

Comment: And I don't even know how is this a usefull comment